# How to use a form feed character in HTML file?

Tags: html

In normal document file the form feed character acts as a page break. How can this be used in an HTML file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't. Use the CSS `page-break-*` properties instead.

- [inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)
- [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after)
- [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before)

For example:

```
article {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this and give me some clue that if it is possible to do what I am trying to achieve
here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381913/creating-a-text-file-in-java-with-bold-formatting-of-headings
?

Comment: Haven't a clue. If you want a Word document, then make a Word document, don't pretend an HTML document is a Word document.

Comment: But there are no packages available in Java SDK for creating a word file and what I am trying to do is working fine except for the page break character.